# Evaluate a line integral using the fundamental theorem of line integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

Consider the vector field $${\mathbf F}(x,y)=(e^x)(\sin y){\mathbf i}+(e^x)(\cos y){\mathbf j},$$ and the curve $C$ composed of the graph of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=5$ followed by segment from $(25,0)$ to $(0,0)$. Evaluate the line integral $$\int_C {\mathbf F} \cdot d {\mathbf r}.$$
I noticed that ${\mathbf F}(x,y)$ is conservative, so I applied the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integral and got the potential function $$f(x,y)=(e^x)(\sin y),$$ matching my professor's answer key. I then did $f(0,0)-f(25,0)$ to get an answer of $0$, but in my professor's answer key he used $f(0,0)-f(0,25)$ to get an answer of $-\sin(25)$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
F(0,0)-F(0,25)&=e^{0}\sin(0)-e^0\sin(25) \\
&=1\cdot 0-1\cdot\sin(25)\\
&=-\sin(25)
\end{align*}

**Edit**

The graph of 
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=5$$  is the portion of a parabola going from $(0,25)$ to $(25,0)$, which you must include as part of your integral. So the integral starts at $(0,25)$, traverses the parabola, then goes to $(0,0)$ along the $x-axis$. **So the start point is $(0,25)$ and the end point is $(0,0)$.**

Comment: You are not addressing the OP's question. He understands that $f(0,0) - f(0,25) = - \sin(25)$. He does not understand **why that is what he's supposed to do**.

Comment: Oh woops...ill edit.

Comment: @Mark_Fantini I have made the appropriate edit

Comment: I have reversed the downvote and upvoted. :)